# Leaflet TypeError: this._northEast is undefined

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have some codes used Leaflet and I want to refactor them below one is working:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                    $.post("StatisticsResultServlet",
                    {
                      queryId:queryIdStr,     
                      field:fieldName,
                      groupingLevelValue:groupingLevel,
                      selectedCityName:selectedCity,
                      divideByPopulation:divideByPop,
                      nofLegendGap:numberOfLegendGap,
                      multipliedNormalizationConstant:multipliedConstant
                    },
                    function(data,status){

                        statisticsResultArray = data.resultArray;
                        legendRangeArray = data.legendRanges;

                        var geojsonFeature;
                        if(groupingLevel == 1){
                            geojsonFeature = BOLGE;
                        }else if(groupingLevel ==2){
                            geojsonFeature = IL;
                        }else if(groupingLevel ==3){
                            geojsonFeature = eval(selectedCity);
                        }
                        geojson = L.geoJson(geojsonFeature, {
                        style: style,
                        onEachFeature: onEachFeature
                        });

                        geojson.addTo(map);

                        var southWest  = geojson.getBounds().getSouthWest();
                        var northEast  = geojson.getBounds().getNorthEast();
                        var bounds = new L.LatLngBounds(southWest, northEast);
                        map.fitBounds(bounds);

                        prepareLegend();

                    });

                });
```

This method is too long and I separated to different classes the business logic. Related my class which I got the error is below:

```js
function PolygonService(){
     this.createPolygon = function(geoJsonFeature){....
     this.geoJsonBounds = function(map){
        var boundsOfGeoJson;

        var northEast  = geoJson.getBounds().getNorthEast();
        var southWest  = geoJson.getBounds().getSouthWest();
        boundsOfGeoJson = new L.latLngBounds(southWest, northEast);

        map.fitBounds(boundsOfGeoJson);

    };
```

The error I got

> TypeError: this._northEast is undefined

How to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

what this error tells you is that you've lost the reference to the [L.geoJSON layer](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojson) you have named `geoJson`. It is not in scope in the `geoJsonBounds` function. You need to either pass the `geoJson` layer to the function or define it in a scope this function has access to. Can you post the full code?

Answer (score 1):

What is the size of your geojson? I think you need to register 'layeradd' map event, this event will be called only after the geojson [or any other layer] is properly added to the map. In this event, you can get the layer object and its extent, and then call map.fitBounds(bounds) to zoom to the layer.

Here is the basic code:

```
map.on('layeradd', function (e) {
            var southWest = e.layer.getBounds().getSouthWest();
            var northEast = e.layer.getBounds().getNorthEast();
            var bounds = new L.LatLngBounds(southWest, northEast);
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
        });
```